# Good and free unzipping software for Mac?

Tags: macos, compression

What is a good and free unzipping software for Mac?

Good as in...supporting different types of compressed files and can unlock password protected ones.

The built-in one on Mac doesn't do a good job with password protected files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a big fan of [The Unarchiver](http://wakaba.c3.cx/s/apps/unarchiver.html) - it will unpack just about anything and its FREE.

Right now I use 7-Zip a lot, since it has multi-threading support and can maximize my CoreDuo, but Unarchiver is great as a swiss army knife unpacker.

Comment: I think the Unarchiver is the best option here.

Comment: Me too. After going through some of suggestions, Unarchiver solves my pain most easily and efficiently.

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, `unzip` at the command line is built in and works pretty well. To use it with a password it's:
 `unzip -P PASSWORD_HERE path/to/zip/file.zip`

Answer (score 2):

Somehow [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) hasn't made it onto my system, but it is a great one.

What has made it on however is [unrarX](http://www.unrarx.com) and [Stuffit Expander](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/system_disk_utilities/stuffitexpander.html). Stuffit isn't exactly great but it is required for some of the old legacy compression formats.

Answer (score 0):

7-zip has a Mac port called [p7zip.](http://web.me.com/krmathis/) Another one called [EZ 7z](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/19139) is the same principle but has a nicer interface.