# Advanced file compression software for Mac OSX

Tags: macos, mac, compression, archiving

Back when I used Windows, I always used WinRAR for file compression and decompression. It had a fair amount of options like 'just storage' vs 'hard compression', password protection and archive type.

Now that I use Mac OSX, the only compression possibility I have is the default Finder's Compress to Zip. I downloaded the most popular decompression software "Unarchiver". But this app can't compress other archive types either.

I went for a search but there seem to be hardly any good advanced compression tools that work nice in OSX and have the options WinRAR has. (WinRAR works in OSX but command line only, I'm looking for something with a GUI.)

Any ideas? I strongly prefer freeware. I found [Archiver](http://archiverapp.com) and [StiffIt](http://www.stuffit.com/), but they are both commercial.

Comment: [Keka](http://itunes.apple.com/app/keka/id470158793) maybe? It's not freeware though. However, what "advanced" feature do you actually need?

Comment: @slhck I want to be able to choose either just putting the files in an archive for convenient transport, like a bag. Or really compress it to the smallest possible size.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good and free unzipping software for Mac?](http://superuser.com/questions/16126/good-and-free-unzipping-software-for-mac) also see [What’s a good way to extract .rar files on the Mac?](http://superuser.com/questions/52124/whats-a-good-way-to-extract-rar-files-on-the-mac)

Comment: @techie007 Not a duplicate of those; they only ask about extracting, not compressing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use p7zip from the command-line; there is a GUI for this called [Keka](http://www.kekaosx.com/en/) which appears to fulfil your [requirements](http://www.kekaosx.com/en/doc.php).

Comment: Although I like the rar format and Keka doesn't support it, Keka is indeed one of the best out there

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using the Terminal, there's always `tar` and `gzip` which are bundled with OS X.

There's also [GUI Tar](http://www.edenwaith.com/products/guitar/), which seems to be just a GUI frontend for *nix compression programs (like `tar`).